# Save directly into shared folder on Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to create a doc directly inside a collection?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-doc-directly-inside-a-collection)

The scenario:

I have a shared folder. If I select the folder and press "Create new" and select folder, it creates a new subfolder, so far so good.

But if I create a new document, that document is not saved to that folder, but instead directly to the account, and the only way to move it to the folder is from the main-page/document list.

The question:

Is there a way to save directly into the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is currently possible, but there are [suggestions for this feature](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=2fc7f974f69a9488&hl=en).

Comment: lets hope it will be implemented soon

Comment: The new Google-Drive interface for Google-Docs saves the new document to the folder you're currently in.

Comment: @Belisama You should probably add that as an answer.