# Is there a way to create a doc directly inside a collection?

Tags: google-drive

For the life of me, I wasn't able to figure out how to create a doc inside a Collection.

When I click the Create button, the document is always created at the root level, and I have to find the collection again and drag it to it.

Is there a way to create the doc inside the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the down-arrow menu next to the collection. Choose "Create" and then choose the document type.

[image: Google Docs screen shot]

Comment: Sweet, you just saved me some repeated frustration.

Comment: Always happy to help, especially when it gives me a chance to learn something new (as in this case).

Comment: That's the reason I love all the StackExchange sites - always learning something new! I have actually been thinking about this exact problem for some time now and I have even used the arrow but never noticed the "Create..." item :P